# Convert a list of lists back into a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a long list that is made up of many tuples (over 100)that all contain 3 items that are strings

```
 first_list = ('the','cat','went'),('back','too','scho'),('t/e','s/e/t','o/ve') etc
```

Many of the tuples are identically so i am using the set function to get out a unique set

```
Long_list = set(first_list)
```

i need the list in its original format , but i also need a duplicate list where the data has been cleaned
I need to remove all the "/" and Replace them with "@"
i can t seem to do this process. Initially i  tried creating a foor loop to go through my list and then carry out the find and replace method.

The way i have done it gives me a new list that is made up of items , so the sets of tuples are not retained

```
 for small_tuple in Long_list:

    the_list = list(small_tuple)

    for uncleaned_string in the_list:


            time = uncleaned_string.replace('/','@')
            last_list.append(time)
print last_list
```

Is there a way i can retain my original format of 3 items within tuple when i convert it back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tuple(myList)` will convert `myList` into a tuple, provided that `myList` is something iterable like a `list`, a `tuple`, or a generator.

To convert a lists of lists in a list of tuples, using a list comprehension expression:

```
last_list = [tuple(x) for x in Long_list]
```

or, to also perform your string replacement:

```
last_list = [tuple(y.replace('/', '@') for y in x) for x in Long_list]
```

From Python's reference:

> **tuple( [iterable] )**
>
> Return a tuple whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable‘s items. iterable may be a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable is already a tuple, it is returned unchanged. For instance, `tuple('abc')` returns `('a', 'b', 'c')` and `tuple([1, 2, 3])` returns `(1, 2, 3)`. If no argument is given, returns a new empty tuple, `()`.
>
> [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) is an immutable sequence type, as documented in [Sequence Types — str, unicode, list, tuple, bytearray, buffer, xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq). For other containers see the built in [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) and [`set`] classes, and the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#module-collections) module.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following using a list comprehension converted into a tuple:

```
 for small_tuple in Long_list:

    the_list = list(small_tuple)

    last_list.append(tuple([uncleaned_string.replace('/','@') for uncleaned_string in the_list]))

print last_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
last_list = [tuple(s.replace('/', '@') for s in t) for t in Long_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code to fit your need

```
for small_tuple in Long_list:
    the_list = list(small_tuple)
    res=[]
    for uncleaned_string in the_list:
        time = uncleaned_string.replace('/','@')
        res.append(time)
    last_list.append(tuple(res))
print last_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to remove the duplicates while preserving the order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

x = OrderedDict.fromkeys(first_list)
Long_list = list(x)
```

`Long_list` contains unique tuples with order same as of `first_list`.